# How to submit SearchView?

Tags: android

When I press submit button of SearchView could't go to another activity. How to open another activity when I pressed submit button of SearchView in main activity?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can write your custom View.OnClickListener listener and then for your search view call the  setOnSearchClickListener function and set your custom listener in there.

In your custom listener you can launch the second activity.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can write a custom serchview and can write code for the navigation, as an example the custom searchview can be written as follows

```
public class TheSearchView extends SearchView {
    private boolean mHasFocus;
    private OnOpenListener mOnOpenListener;

    public TheSearchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setOnOpenListener(OnOpenListener onOpenListener) {
        mOnOpenListener = onOpenListener;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        boolean onTouchEvent = super.onTouchEvent(event);

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (!mHasFocus) {
                mHasFocus = true;

                if (mOnOpenListener != null) {
                    mOnOpenListener.onOpen();
                }
            }

            break;
        }

        return onTouchEvent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean gainFocus, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        super.onFocusChanged(gainFocus, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);

        if (!gainFocus) {
            mHasFocus = false;
        }
    }

    public interface OnOpenListener {
        public void onOpen();
    }
}
```

for more and better explanations please visit

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/pro-tip-customize-the-android-search-view-widget/

please go through the document at 
http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html